# A memory peak when App launch caused by VM: CoreUI image data

Tags: ios, memory, instruments

When I launch the App, I use the Instruments Allocation Tools to find memory issues.Then I find the there is a memeory peak ocurs, it is caused by the VM: CoreUI image data, Thank you for telling me which methods will create a lot of VM: CoreUI image data.The memory will rise first and then reduce.

The call stack as the picture shows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAN0p.jpg)

The memory peak casued by the VM: CoreUI image data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKL7q.png)